# How to Split list to a specific length sublist and remaining parts to a separate sublist in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to split a list into sublists of specific length and store the remaining elements in other list.

For example:

```
Initial list is: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,11]
```

I want to divide it into sublists or 3 numbers, and the remaining in a separate sublist.

```
I need result as : [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11]]
```

Comment: `[your_list[i: i+3] for i in range(0, len(your_list), 3)]`

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/967621

Answer (score 5):

You can use `range(start, end, step)`.

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,11]
res = [lst[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(lst), 3)]
print(res)
```

---

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11]]
```